# date time to date (Y/m/d)

Tags: php, date-formatting

I have this as my date if I use `$patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']` just as.

> 28/07/2012 00:00:00

but when I do this to get it to a Y/m/d format it goes back to

> 1970/01/01

```
$timestamp = strtotime($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']);
$AdmissionDate = date('Y/m/d', $patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']);
```

Why is this. Whats happening in `strtotime`?

UPDATE.

there is still something funny here.

`$timestamp = strtotime($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']);`

still give no value, but doing

`echo $patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']`

gives me the correct date.

any idea

`var_dump` returns `boolean false` and `var_dump($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM'])` returns string `'28/07/2012 00:00:00' (length=19)`

**SOLUTION**

strtotime(str_replace("/", ".", $patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the timestamp / are using the wrong variable (the original date time), if the code you posted is correct:

```
$AdmissionDate = date('Y/m/d', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Hi. the `$timestamp = strtotime($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']);` still give no value, but doing `echo $patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']` gives me the correct date. any idea

Comment: @morne: Have you tried `var_dump($timestamp)`? What is the output?

Comment: returns `boolean false` and var_dump($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']) returns `string '28/07/2012 00:00:00' (length=19)`

Comment: @morne: I think I had this problem a few weeks before. Try `strtotime(str_replace("/", ".", $patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']));`

Comment: That was Spot on. Thanks a lot. Could you please up me one for the minus. I dont think it was such a bad problem in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using wrong variable:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']);
$AdmissionDate = date('Y/m/d', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Hi. the `$timestamp = strtotime($patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']);` still give no value, but doing `echo $patient['DATE_UNIT_ADM']` gives me the correct date. any idea